# Having the login system work inside the popup with redirect after submitting

Tags: php, authentication, popup

I've noticed my old question has gotten closed due to lack of details and information.

Basically what I need is the current login system to work inside my Popup plugin.

http://justxp.plutohost.net/test3/

Click on the 'Login' button to open up the popup.

I need Username form, password form, submit form working with the login system I have.

That's how I call the popup:

```
<a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="myModal"><img src="img/login.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='img/hover1.png'" 
onmouseout="this.src='img/login.png'"></a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
<h1>Login</h1>
<p>Please enter your username and password carefully.</p>
</form>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

The plugin I use for my popup modal: http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

This is my login.php, I really don't understand how have they done the login system in this one:

http://pastebin.com/WegLBhYi

That script basically prints out error messages, and when logged in, it redirects to member.php file.

What do I want:

I want this exact login system to work the same inside the popup, When logged in successfully, it will redirect you to member.php too, if login failed, it will redirect you to logerror.php (a new page with the same layout) and show the error message & allow you to re-log in again.

This is my header.php, it basically shows the layout for logged users or guests

http://pastebin.com/XCcnNiKg

If you have any idea on how to get the login working with this code, that'd be really nice!
This script is really bad coded as you see.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form inside your lightbox login has no action on it. Look at line 40 of the HTML Source. So right now the form is just submitting to the same page and sending the info as GET variables. I don't see in your PHP code where you create the myModal div but you need to add an action that sends info to a php file that can check the login and password against your database, it can then redirect to member.php or the logerror.php

Also FYI You have two different versions of Jquery being loaded.

Comment: So you're saying there is no way to get the login working on the modal?

Comment: I don't know, you posted above code that includes <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">...</div> but i don't see that code in your pastebin code examples. If you can modify what is in that div then you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to include my layout HTML code with the modal in it,  Ive tried putting action-login.php but it gives me errors.
HTML: http://pastebin.com/MRKD6D3W

Comment: Warning: require(includes/inc.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/justxpp1/public_html/test3/login.php on line 2

Warning: require(includes/inc.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/justxpp1/public_html/test3/login.php on line 2

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'includes/inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/justxpp1/public_html/test3/login.php on line 2

Comment: http://slyfiles.com/ I got it to work without errors but on login, it just redirects to the login.php page, after putting action=login.php

Comment: You need to setup your login.php file to handle the incoming data and validate the login then redirect to the appropriate page.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this?